# Admin form not validating in a module

Tags: 7, commerce

I am coding a Drupal Module wich limits the node creation to users who bought some products.
e.g. A user bought a 5 photos + 5 videos pack, the module limits his number of photos & videos he can create to 5.

I got an issue with the admin form :

```
function product_node_limit_admin($form, &$form_state) {

    foreach ($products = product_node_limit_get_products() as $result) {

        $product = commerce_product_load($result->product_id);

        $form[$product->title] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => $product->title,
            '#collapsible' => TRUE,
            '#collapsed' => FALSE,
            '#tree' => TRUE
        );

        $form[$product->title]['cumul'] = array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => t('Cumulative'),
            '#required' => FALSE,
        );

        $value = variable_get($product->title, 1);

        foreach ($types = product_node_limit_types() as $type) {

            $form[$product->title][$type['type']] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => $type['name'],
                '#size' => 10,
                '#maxlength' => 10,
                '#required' => FALSE,
                // '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => ($value[$type['type']] != '') ? $value[$type['type']] : 0),
                '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'),
                '#default_value' => ($value[$type['type']] != '') ? $value[$type['type']] : 0,
            );

        }

    }

    return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

[image: The form]

This gives me a form but when I submit it I got an error (the inputs are not recognized as integers even if I put integers in them)
, and when I dump the $form_state after validation, the ['#values'] index has no values (and the ['#input'] index has the good values). So Drupal doesn't save the values to the variable table.

I dumped the $value and it was empty, and when I put 7 in the '#default_value' index, $value got 7. I think the issue is in the default_value index.

I checked on the stack and found a topic just like this but the answer didn't helped me at all .

How comes the ['#values'] stays empty ?

Here is the menu_hook I did

```
function product_node_limit_menu(){

    $items = array();

    $items['admin/commerce/config/product_node_limit'] = array(
        'title' => 'Product node limit',
        'description' => 'Exemple de configuration ',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('product_node_limit_admin'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'file' => 'product_node_limit.admin.inc',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the solution was so simple it makes me cry : 
'DO NOT PUT SPACES IN THE $FORM ARRAY KEYS'.

It works like a charm since I replaced ' ' by '_' in the array keys. I feel so stupid ...

Answer (score 0):

The value which u are accessing in default value, always set conditions to 0, so which Drupal considers not be a positive Integer.

What u can do is:

```
'#default_value' => (variable_get($type['type']) != '' )?variable_get($type['type']):0,
```

It will not give u error, and will show your values when it is saved.